# Can a Vulnerability Management tool highlight BIOS and driver-level vulnerabilities?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, bios, driver

Several known vulnerabilities affect BIOS (Reference URLs below). So my question is, are the Vulnerability Management tools (such as Nessus, NeXpose, Qualys, etc) technically capable of highlighting BIOS and driver-level vulnerabilities? Is this something that can be detected for example via an authenticated Windows scan?

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-3582
http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerability/bios-bummer-new-malware-can-bypass-bios/240155473
http://searchcloudsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/BIOS-rootkit-attack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessus does not have a plugin for that CVE. You can check this using the [Nessus plugin search](http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=search). I don't know about the other tools.

In theory it is possible to detect these issues on an authenticated scan, as you can do a WMI query for the BIOS version. It may turn out that there are particular difficulties that prevent this; perhaps the BIOS version doesn't update when you apply the new firmware. Or it may just be that Tenable haven't yet developed such a plugin.

Nessus does have checks for some driver vulnerabilities (e.g. [Nvidia flaw](http://www.scip.ch/en/?vuldb.5292)) They are generally local checks only, although a few remote ones exist (Etherleak is one that springs to mind).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Python program that invokes Intel CHIPSEC module, and generate SCAP output, instead of the normal non-SCAP output that CHIPSEC uses.
But, SCAP has no OVAL definitions for BIOS/UEFI/firmware, so any BIOS results will likely only be found via full-text-search, until OVAL problem is fixed.
HTH, Lee. http://firmwaresecurity.com/feed